# Displaying Google Plus user profile picture in Android app

Tags: android, google-plus

Am trying to display the profile picture of users logged into my app through Google+ but am not sure how to do this.To get the image (and other information), google provides the code

```
@Override
public void onConnected() {
...
if (mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson() != null) {
    Person currentPerson = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson();
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
}
}
```

I am aware that ordinarily i would need to get any image i want to display from `res/drawable...` but i don't know what to do with the value of `personPhoto` (which somehow get's changed from type `String` to `Image` when you paste the code in Eclipse.

Comment: There is a helper class in Google Play services for loading images returned from it: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use that URL to grab the photo as a bitmap and set it to an imageview.

Section 4.9 of this article explains how to make an asynctask that will do just that:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Answer (score 5):

First you need to add this dependency in your  app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'}
```

After this update your UI Accordingly :

```
private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (account != null){
        text.setText("Sign in as :" +account.getDisplayName());
        email.setText(account.getEmail());
        String imgurl = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        Glide.with(this).load(imgurl).into(profile);
        sighIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sighOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        text.setText("signOut");
        sighIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sighOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked on my Android app. I developed it from an answer above by Naveen Kumar Yadav.

*Prerequisites*
- I am using a Google Sign-In API for my login.
- I have an XML Code with an ImageView that has an id "client_dp"

Add this dependency to your app-level build.gradle file

```
dependencies {compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'}
```

Then add this code to your activity java file

```
//Firebase get user info
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser account = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (account != null){         
        //Display User Image from Google Account
        //Objects.requireNonNull() prevents getPhotoUrl() from returning a NullPointerException
        String personImage = Objects.requireNonNull(account.getPhotoUrl()).toString();
        ImageView userImage = findViewById(R.id.client_dp);
        Glide.with(this).load(personImage).into(userImage);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With new google sign in Options in Kotlin. Simply request for the parameters you need in your onCreate function

```
   val gso = 
     GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString("your-client-id"))
        .requestEmail()
        .requestProfile()
        .requestId()
        .build()
```

When recieving back the response from google Sign in activity, inside the

```
Get user profile picture through:
    val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account?.idToken, null)

val photoUrl = credential.photoUrl.toString()
```